# Estimate the determinant of sparse 0-1 matrix

Tags: determinants, sparse-matrices

There is a matrix A where each entry is either 0 or 1. Each column has exactly a 1's and each row has at most b 1's. What's the upper bound of abs(|A|)? 
The condition is stronger than the Hadamard's maximal determinant problem. Is there any known result?

Comment: GramSchmidt should give a^(n/2) as an upper bound.  How tight do you need?

Comment: Also, for $a=4$ and $n=7k$,one can get a lower bound of $32^k=4^{5n/14}$, so I expect one can't improve the bound much unlless b is close to n.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379518302593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a previous answer disappeared, so I will expand on my comments.

Using that a determinant corresponds to the volume of a parallelipiped, an immediate
upper bound (using columns) of $a^{n/2}$ results.  If you know the distribution across the
rows, use the product of their lengths (don't forget the square root) for a slightly better bound.

There also has been work done on determinants of (I think binary but am not sure) matrices with constant row sums.  I do not have any names or dates come to mind, but I suspect the work has been 
cited here on MO.  You might succeed with a web search for "constant row sum".